# Android app don't find cPanel file URL

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley, cpanel

I've uploaded some .php files to my server which uses cPanel in order to connect to a MySQL database stored on the same server. Those files are on public_html/myfiles. Then I guess that my URL to a file would be "www.myserver.com/myfiles/file2.php"

I'm trying to determine if my Android app can find it or not with this code:

```
public boolean exists(String URLName){
        try {
            HttpURLConnection con =
                    (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
            con.setFollowRedirects(false);
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            con.setDoOutput(false);
            return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

URLName = "www.myserver.com/myfiles/file2.php"

This method is returning false.

I also tried using Volley with the following code:

```
private void getData() {
        String id = "1";
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        String url = "www.myserver.com/myfiles/file2.php?id="+id;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Log.d("VOLLEY RESPONSE",s);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.d("VOLLEY ERROR","Error");
            }
        });

                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

But I get a VolleyError which doesn't give much info.. It just return a 500 "Server Error".

How can I do this? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: look at the error logs for details about the 500.

Comment: I don't get any details about it. If I try to get error.getMessage() on method "onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)", app crashes saying it's null. @MarcB

Comment: " [58440] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for www.myserver.com/myfiles/file2.php?id=1 " is what I get first. Then when I print error stack trace I get "com.android.volley.ServerError". @MarcB

Comment: you need to look at the webserver's error log. 500 means something blew up over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was a problem on the .php code on those files (I wasn't writing '?>' to close the file), nothing to do with Android Java coding. It's working fine with JsonObjectRequest and StringRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this in case of Volley :

```
 URL = String.format("http://www.example.com/test/?val_1=%1$s&val_2=%2$s",first,second);
```

Comment: does your server allow to receive get or post method?

Answer (score 0):

Use **JsonObjectRequest** alogn with this url....

```
final String url = "http://httpbin.org/get?param1=hello";
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                    // display response     
        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
        Log.d("Error.Response", response);
   }
}); 


queue.add(getRequest);
```

Check [this](http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put) out also

Comment: That method is working fine. When I use my URL along with this method, I get the same error again.. How can I check whether my server allows to receive get/post method or not?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and used `GET` for both `php` and `java` code then got response as expected.

```
    StringRequest strObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "http://www.mpworld.in/test.php?name="+trainNumber+"&email="+date+"&question="+date,
            listener, errorListener)
```